# How to check condition that 'only one jRadiobutton should be selected'

Tags: java, swing

I am working on details entry form on NetBeans with Java Swings. There are three certain jRadiobutton, of them **only one must be selected**. 
Any methods that could give such power, please suggest. Or might I need to custom my own method to perform check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create a object of `ButtonGroup` and add radio buttons to that object.

```
JRadioButton birdButton = new JRadioButton(birdString);
birdButton.setSelected(true);

JRadioButton catButton = new JRadioButton(catString);

   //Group the radio buttons.
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(birdButton);
group.add(catButton);
```